# EV3 Device Manager ghost on my mac - how to remove?

Tags: ev3, software, mac

TLDR: how to remove EV3 software completely from Mac?

A year ago I got a used Mindstorms EV3 set, fired it up and played around with my son who was 8 at the time. I installed a setup where we could write Python scripts to control the robot. But it was too time consuming and maybe my son just didn't get a big spark for robotics, so we stopped using it.

I think I uninstalled the parts that I could, but lately some EV3 manager part has started running itself in the background erroneously, consuming 90% of CPU and heating up the computer. I can stop the process from Activity Monitor. But I struggle to find and remove this program. I have no clue why it fires up randomly!

Any help?

Comment: Probably best asked on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about LEGO directly, it is a question about how to uninstall a running service on Windows, which is better answered on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: The answer is very specific to this specific software package, so, in this case, I think this Q&A is better suited to this site rather than other more generic Stack Exchange sties.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, the *EV3 Device Manager* program is located at `/Library/EV3 Device Manager`. This directory contains an uninstaller. You can run it from a terminal window like this:

```
/Library/EV3 Device Manager/uninstall.command
```

Note: you will be prompted for your password since the uninstall requires administrative privileges.

---

Background:

The *EV3 Device Manager* is a background service that serves as a communication bridge to allow https://ev3manager.education.lego.com to connect to your EV3, so it is only needed if you want to use that website to do firmware updates.